# Can duplicate descriptions cause an AdSense application rejection?

Tags: google-adsense, google-adsense-policies

I want to run ads on my website. Traffic is more then 500 visitors per day.

I submitted my website for AdSense more than a month ago. Google replied to me that the website don't comply with Google AdSense policies.

At that time there were duplicate descriptions on 5000 pages which where showing errors in Google Webmaster Tools. I think that was the issue.

Now I have removed those duplicate descriptions. Can I apply for Adsense again?

Comment: Can you share more information from the email they sent you?   Google AdSense usually puts specific reasons in their rejection letters.   Duplicate meta description errors from Google Webmaster Tools shouldn't have anything to do with it.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, check all Google AdSense policies and try to make your blog user friendly. Your blog should be clear and informative, don't use complicated blog design. Always post good content. Don't share any pirated software, hacking tricks, or any other useless things.

Answer (score 0):

Duplication can be a big factor. If title or meta description tags are duplicated within pages, then google might begin to think that the two pages are nearly the same. This can be worse if the tags are duplicated across different domains especially if one is managed by someone else.

If you want adsense, read the policies and avoid duplicate content, avoid keyword stuffing, make unique content, and by content, it means words that any web browser (including the old text browser, lynx) can display, make all links valid (that means no links to error pages), and aim for at least 200 to 300 words per page if not more, but don't go too crazy and go for 5000+ words a page.